# Sending a webpage as the content of an email

Tags: php, email

I made a table, injecting PHP into the table instead of using Javascript to add values, place values, etc.

I'm trying to keep ONE version of this file, but there also needs to be the option to send the same file by email.

I tried using `file_get_contents()` but it didn't run the PHP code I put on that page.

Is there any way I can get the version of the file that the client sees and then email it, or do I have to rewrite the copy all over again?

FYI, I'm a PHP amatur, so if you use any functions, please be prepared to either link to a good example or explain.

Here's 
a little bit of my table, if it helps...

```
<td class="left_bar">
<b>Pace</b>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo(round($finance_array[4], 2)); ?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo(round($finance_array[5], 2)); ?>
</td>
<td>
<?php $sum = $finance_array[4] + $finance_array[5];
echo(round($sum, 2)); ?>    
</td>
```

Comment: So if your table geentared by php - then add result of generated code to email content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use output buffering to get output into a variable (in this example `$output`), then you can `echo $output`, write it to a file or use `$output` in a mail() call, etc.

```
ob_start();
// All content here
// Maybe include "file.php";
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output;
```

Comment: That sounds right, but I don't understand how it works.. .could you explain?

Comment: You can read the manual of [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) which has a lot of explanation.  `While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer. `  ob_get_clean stops output buffering and returns what is in the internal buffer.